# Problems in moving a register value to a memory address in assembly language using fasm assembler?

Tags: assembly, fasm

I am really confused about this one thing. I was following the book assembly programming for x86 processors and i was reading about the mov instructions and how it works. So, the author said that the following instruction is valid
mov mem,reg.....basically moving a register value to a memory address.

Now this what i tried and i keep getting this error called invalid operand. Can someone please explain me what exactly is the error.

```
#fasm#

 mov ax,[var] ;the value 67 is moved to the ax register works perfect
 mov myvar,ax ; my aim is to move the value 67 to the memory location of ;myvar but then i keep getting this error - Invalid operand? why is that?

var: dw 67   
myvar: dw ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this:

```
mov [myvar], ax
```

- `myvar` is a constant holding the address of the memory allocated for the variable.
- `[myvar]` instructs to fetch/store a value in memory at the address pointed by `myvar`

So:

```
mov ax, myvar  ; load the address of myvar in ax
mov ax, [myvar]; load the value stored at address myvar
mov [myvar], ax; store the value of ax at address myvar
```

Comment: :- Thank u. I tried it before and it works. But doesn't it mean that i am moving the value to the variable instead of moving it to its memory address?

Comment: I don't get the difference between the two. Are you saying that `myvar` contains the address where you want to put the value ?

Comment: :- Yeah thats what i meant because when i deference myvar to [myvar] i get the value and when i move myvar to a register, i see the address of myvar being copied to the register.

Comment: myvar dw ? ; This means the assembler allocates a memory address and labels that address as myvar. If you wish your second line to work, you need to inform the assembler of its type. So, the instruction that will work is mov word ptr myvar,ax ; The word ptr is a assmbler reserved mnemonic.

Comment: @quasar66 - this is not FASM syntax! In FASM, if you want to override the label type you must use `mov  word [myvar], ax`; If myvar is defined by `dw`, only `mov [myvar], ax` is enough and recommended.